# Unable to source property name containing dot in shell script

Tags: shell, properties

I have a property file(env.properties) that contains below property name and value:

```
oracle.install.option=UPGRADE_DB
```

I have another shell script (test.sh) that runs source command and try to access the value of property oracle.install.option :

```
#!/bin/sh
source env.properties
echo "value is...... " $oracle.install.option
```

When I run the file .test.sh, I am unable to get the value of above property. Output:

```
env.properties: line 1: oracle.install.option=UPGRADE_DB: command not found
value is ......... .install.option
```

My expected output is `UPGRADE_DB`. Kindly assist me in getting this resolved.

Comment: are you sure it is a shell file? not an oracle config file? because env. variables and dots don't mix well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This properties file is not a shell file, and dots are not allowed in environment variable names (read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93532/exporting-a-variable-with-dot-in-it))
So your hack could have worked if the properties had no dot in them, but not here.

So if you want to display it in your shell, you have another good alternative: parse the properties file using `awk`

```
 awk -F= '{if ($1=="oracle.install.option") print "value is......",$2}' env.properties
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.